# Xamarin reuse viewmodel on user control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my MainPage.xaml, which is a ContentPage, I have two user controls.
Both of which are ContentView and are loaded like this:

```
<local:MyView2 HorizontalOptions="Start" 
               VerticalOptions="Fill">
    <local:MyView2.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:NavbarViewModel />
    </local:MyView2.BindingContext>
    <local:MyView2.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="{x:Type local:MyView2}" Binding="{Binding IsPresented}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <local:MenuTrigger IsPresented="True"/>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <local:MenuTrigger IsPresented="False" />
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>        
    </local:MyView2.Triggers>
</local:MyView2>
// omitted myview1, they are basically the same
```

My MainPage has a different viewmodel than MyView1 and 2 which are the contentviews.
But the bindingcontext I have said is not accessible from inside the contentview:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Universal_ONE.MyView1"
         x:Name="MyView1Name">

  <Frame BackgroundColor="#385C6C"
         Padding="0,0,0,0">
      <ImageButton Source="outline_menu_white_24.png" 
                   Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyView1Name}, Path=PresentMenu}}"
                   WidthRequest="24" 
                   HeightRequest="24" 
                   Margin="15,0,0,0"
                   BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  />
  </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

I also tried it like this:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Universal_ONE.MyView1">

  <Frame BackgroundColor="#385C6C"
         Padding="0,0,0,0">
    <ImageButton Source="outline_menu_white_24.png" 
                   Command="{Binding PresentMenu}"
                   WidthRequest="24" 
                   HeightRequest="24" 
                   Margin="15,0,0,0"
                   BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  />
  </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

The error I get on the PresentMenu: No DataContext found for binding PresentMenu

How do I access the bindingcontext inside my contentview?
If it was not clear already, the contentviews are in a seperate file.

EDIT:
NavbarViewModel:

```
public class NavbarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public NavbarViewModel()
    {
        isPresented = false;
        PresentMenu = new Command(() => IsPresented = !IsPresented);
    }

    bool isPresented;
    public bool IsPresented
    {
        get => isPresented;
        set
        {
            isPresented = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsPresented)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ICommand PresentMenu { private set; get; }
}
```

EDIT 2:
I have added:

```
x:DataType="viewmodels:NavbarViewModel
```

To both contentviews, this removes the error that it has no DataContext. However, the binding still does not work.

Working solution:
I have now added the viewmodel as a staticresource in app.xaml and just reuse that everywhere including in the user controls. I hope to look at this again at some point in the future.

Comment: please post `NavbarViewModel`

Comment: @Jason I have added the viewmodel code and the error I get

Comment: are you doing anything in the code behind to modify the BindingContext?

Comment: No it only has initializeComponent(). I have not touched any codebehind in from any file

Comment: I can upload the whole to a Github repo if you'd like

Comment: I have found this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/178994/pass-reference-of-viewmodel-to-another-xaml-file. However, this looks very cumbersome to do if for every reusable piece of xaml I have to bind a context that way.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to have a shared ViewModel that I instantiate and add as a resource in the app?

Comment: Please add your solution *as an answer*, so that people know that the question has been answered (without having to come here and read to the bottom of the question). After 48 hours, you can then accept your answer.

Comment: Well that's still not really a proper solution to my problem